# Problem with deleting object in recyclerview in Realm

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I have problem with deleting object in recyclerview. When I clicking button in RV item I have error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: This field(id) is not nullable. Error is in this line in RealmHelper:   RealmResults results = realm.where(Task.class).equalTo("id", taskID).findAll();

MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IRecyclerItemClickListener {

```
@Nullable
@BindView(R.id.floating_button) FloatingActionButton floatingButton;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
MainAdapter mainAdapter;

Realm realm;
RealmHelper realmHelper;
RealmResults<Task> results;
List<Task> tasks;
String taskID;
int position;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);



    realmHelper = new RealmHelper(realm);
    tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    tasks = realmHelper.getAllTasks();

    mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(tasks,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    onDeleteClick(position);

}


@Optional
@OnClick(R.id.floating_button)
public void onClick() {

    android.app.Fragment fragment = new TaskFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}


public void showFloatingActionButton() {
    floatingButton.show();
}


public void hideFloatingActionButton() {
    floatingButton.hide();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    showFloatingActionButton();
    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    realm.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {

    realmHelper.deleteTask(taskID, position);
    Log.d(TAG, "ON DELETE CLICK " + taskID);

}
```

}

RealmHelper:

```
public class RealmHelper {

Realm realm;

private  static ArrayList<Task> taskArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String TAG = "RealmHelper";
MainAdapter mainAdapter;


public RealmHelper(Realm realm) {
    this.realm = realm;
}


public void saveTask(final Task task) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Task t = realm.copyToRealm(task);
        }
    });

}


public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
   RealmResults<Task> taskResult = realm.where(Task.class).findAll();

    return taskResult;
}


public void deleteTask( String taskID, int position) {
    RealmResults<Task> results = realm.where(Task.class).equalTo("id", taskID).findAll();
    if (results.size() != 0) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
        realm.commitTransaction();
        taskArrayList.remove(position);
        mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Clearly `taskID` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MainActivity`, you define a `taskID` field but you never initialize it. That means it has the default value for a String, which is `null`.

I'm guessing that each `Task` object in your `tasks` list has an id of some sort. Since you're already getting a position argument, you can use that to fetch the id on the fly.

```
@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    Task task = tasks.get(position);
    String id = task.getTaskID(); // or whatever the correct call is
    realmHelper.deleteTask(id, position);

    Log.d(TAG, "ON DELETE CLICK " + taskID);
}
```

Comment: Wow! You are right! It was so simple and I did not see it. Thank you!